# Getting str.count () to work on python

Tags: python

I'm very new to programming. And I've been trying to get the string.count function to work. 
This is what I have so far:

```
def trial ():
    a = raw_input ("Enter a string:").lower() 
    print a
    b = raw_input ("Enter a substring:").lower()
    print b

    print "The total character count is:" + a.count('b')
```

It's still not giving me the count number. It keeps giving me `<built-in method count of str object at 0x0181B500>`. 
I figure I'm doing something wrong. I realize this might be a simple question, but I'm a beginner. I read you have to use str.count (sub[,start[,end]]) but what does the start and end mean? I read the description but I didn't really get it.

Any kind of help will be appreciated!

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Can you provide a sample input and expected output?

Comment: I don't believe this is your actual code because this code doesn't print that output. Please post something more representative.

Comment: `a.count('b')` must be `str(a.count('b'))` to let the print work. or even `str(a.count(b))` to let the search work.

Comment: def stringCount ():
 stringCount = raw_input ("Enter a string:").lower()
 print stringCount
 subCount = raw_input ("Enter a substring:").lower()
 print subCount                                                      And the output should be something like this. Enter a string: she sells sea shells. Enter a substring: sh. >>> 2 (There are two occurrences of sh). @MarkRansom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message you're receiving comes from running either `a.count` or `b.count`. When you don't include the parens on an object method, you are accessing the method object directly as represented in the message.

Your algorithm is incorrect. `a.count('b')` will return the total number of occurrences of the character 'b' in a. Your print message says that it's displaying the "The total character count". To do that you would use the `len()` function. To get the total number of characters in `a` you would run `len(a)` and for `b` you would run `len(b)`. If you're trying to get the total for both you would run `len(a) + len(b)` or `len(a + b)` if you're trying to get the total number of occurrences of `b` in `a` then you would run `a.count(b)`.

Comment: It worked!! Thanks a lot for the help and explaining everything in simple terms! :)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't saved your code or are otherwise using `print a.count` and not `print a.count()`. The former means that you are printing the representation of the `count` method in the string object,hence the print out:

```
<built-in method count of str object at 0x0181B500>
```

As for what the `sub,start,end` means, might I recommend [the Python documentation for string objects?](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count)

> ```
> string.count(s, sub[, start[, end]])
> ```
>
> Return the number of (non-overlapping) occurrences of substring sub in string s[start:end]. Defaults for start and end and interpretation of negative values are the same as for slices.

In essence, this means that:

```
"Some long text right about here".count("o",5,9)
```

Will only calculate the number of `o`s in the substring `"Some long text right about here"[5:9]` which is equivilent to `"long"`, so will return `1`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to print how many times `b` occurs in `a`? By passing `'b'`, you're getting the number of times the letter `b` is present in the string, not the contents of the `b` variable. Additionally, you're attempting to concatenate a string and an int. Please make the following adjustments.

```
def trial ():
    a = raw_input ("Enter a string:").lower() 
    print a
    b = raw_input ("Enter a substring:").lower()
    print b

    print "The total character count is:" + str(a.count(b))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we could not able to understand your question , You want no of character to be counted or count occurrence of single character.
Below code count no of character involved.

```
from collections import Counter
 str = "Mary had a little lamb"
 counter = Counter(str)
 print Counter[str]
```

below code only character

```
str= raw_input("Enter anything:")
str = "this is string example....wow!!!";
sub = "i";
print "str.count(sub) : ", str.count(sub)
```

Answer (score 1):

For testing purposes it's good practice to separate logic from the I/O

eg:.

```
def trial(a, b):
    return "The total character count is:" + a.count('b')
```

Now you can quickly test like this

```
>>> trial("foo bar", "oo")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in trial
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Oh right, the preferred way is to use .format()

```
def trial(a, b):
    return "The total character count is: {}".format(a.count('b'))
```

Now you can test it again

```
>>> trial("foo bar", "oo")
'The total character count is: 1'
```

Your original error was not generated by the code in your question. You probably had something like this

```
def trial ():
    a = raw_input ("Enter a string:").lower() 
    print a
    b = raw_input ("Enter a substring:").lower()
    print b

    print "The total character count is:", a.count
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question using python 3.3.1.

According to your example

```
def trial () :
    a = input ("Enter a string:").lower()
    #takes your input in lower case and assign to variable a 
    print (a)
    #print above input (content of a)
    b = input ("Enter a substring:").lower()
    #takes your input in lower case and assign to variable b
    print (b)
    #print above input (content of b)

    print ("The total character count is:", a.count(b))
    #this will give you how many times content of 'b' repeat in content of 'a'.

trial()
```

str.count(sub,start,end) ->
your example 'str' is equals to 'a'. 'sub' is equals to 'b'. start and end were not given. So default start is index 0 of 'a' and default end is last index of 'a'. Assume your a='beautiful_mind_sing' and b='i'. If you give a.count(b,1,13). Even though there are three 'i' s the answer will 2 Because here start and end indexes are 1 and 13. Therefore a.count() is searching index 1 to 13 only. Here between the range 'e' and 'd' -> 'b*e*autiful_min*d*_sing'.

Additional example:

```
first_line='Hello Sandu how are you? Hello Anu how are you? Hello Sa how are you?'
searching_word='are'

print("Number of searching_word 'are' repeate in the first_line is: ", first_line.count(searching_word,3,50))
```

Answer:

> > > Number of searching_word 'are' repeate in the first_line is:  2

refer: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_count.htm